# Unsupported nesting LOCAL error with Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm getting a strange error while using hilt. It doesn't get compiled and stops with the error `Unsupported nesting LOCAL`. I don't see any dependency graph issue with hilt config. Has anyone come across this issue?
These are the versions I'm using

Java: `11`

Hilt: `com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42`

`com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2:42`

`androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0`

Following is the stacktrace

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
```

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':demo:hiltJavaCompileDebug'.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported nesting LOCAL

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':demo:hiltJavaCompileRelease'.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported nesting LOCAL
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.JvmDescriptorUtilsKt.getInternalName(JvmDescriptorUtils.kt:73)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.JvmDescriptorUtilsKt.getDescriptor(JvmDescriptorUtils.kt:86)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.JvmDescriptorTypeVisitor.visitDeclared(JvmDescriptorUtils.kt:185)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.JvmDescriptorTypeVisitor.visitDeclared(JvmDescriptorUtils.kt:180)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1151)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.JvmDescriptorUtilsKt.descriptor(JvmDescriptorUtils.kt:148)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.JvmDescriptorUtilsKt.descriptor(JvmDescriptorUtils.kt:167)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.JvmDescriptorUtilsKt.descriptor(JvmDescriptorUtils.kt:57)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.KotlinMetadataElement.getDescriptor(KotlinMetadataElement.kt:53)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.kotlin.KotlinMetadataElement.getFunctionMetadata(KotlinMetadataElement.kt:73)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacMethodElement$kotlinMetadata$2.invoke(JavacMethodElement.kt:73)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacMethodElement$kotlinMetadata$2.invoke(JavacMethodElement.kt:72)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacMethodElement.getKotlinMetadata(JavacMethodElement.kt:72)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacMethodElement$name$2.invoke(JavacMethodElement.kt:50)
at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacMethodElement$name$2.invoke(JavacMethodElement.kt:49)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232742201). It seems to be a non-descriptive error message from hilt. I was using a private function as a provider where I missed `@Provides`. Removing `private` and adding `@Provides` Solved the issue